# Hi, i am trying to do an app that counts your clicks using python, tkinter. The problem is that the buttons won't work. Can someone help me?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
counter = 0
def counter_label (label):
    counter = 0
    def count():
        global counter
        counter+=1
        label.config(text = str(counter))
        label.after(1000, count)
    count()

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("250x200")
root.title("Vladuzz208 SRL")

label = tk.Label(root, text = "Cronometru", font = ('Arial', 18))
label.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)

Cronometru = tk.Label (root, fg = "White")
Cronometru.pack(padx = 20, pady = 10)
counter_label(Cronometru)

def ambda():
    print(counter)

button = tk.Button(root, text = "Memoreaza", width = 15, command = ambda)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, please post the full traceback. And always include a description of the problem you're having. Saying something "won't work" doesn't give us much to go on.

Comment: If you want to count the clicks, you should increase the global `counter` inside `ambda()`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @acw1668 mentioned you should move the `counter` inside `ambda()` however, it could also be simplified quite a bit and if you want your label to update correctly you should move that also.  Maybe this will help.

```
import tkinter as tk

counter = 0

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("250x200")
root.title("Vladuzz208 SRL")

label = tk.Label(root, text = "Cronometru", font = ('Arial', 18))
label.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)

def ambda():
    global counter
    counter+=1
    print(counter)
    label.config(text=counter)


button = tk.Button(root, text = "Memoreaza", width = 15, command = ambda)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, I am trying to do an app that counts your clicks using python,
> tkinter. The problem is that the buttons won't work.

The problem can be fixed by using `import partial`.

Add `tk.IntVar()`

Script, just 28 lines:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Increasing counter")


def increase_counter(var: int, amount: int) -> int:
   result=var.get()
   result += amount
   
   var.set(result)

variable = tk.IntVar()

btn = tk.Button(root,
          width=10,
          text="Increase",
          command=partial(increase_counter, variable, +1))
            
btn.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=10)

tk.Label(root,
         width=5,
         height=2,
         textvariable=variable).grid(column=0, row=1,padx=20, pady=10)
    
root.mainloop()

variable = tk.IntVar()

btn = tk.Button(root,
          width=10,
          text="Increase",
          command=partial(do_something,
                          variable, +1))
            
btn.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=10)

tk.Label(root,
         width=5,
         height=2,
         textvariable=variable).grid(column=0, row=1,padx=20, pady=10)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]